# Pass through a box collider but still execute OnCollisionStay function

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, game-physics

I'm making a 2D game in which the player can grab and drop some objects. I'm using the `OnCollisionStay` function to do it. The problem is that my player needs to be "touching" the box to grab it and I thought that making 2 collision boxes at the left and right of him without a mesh renderer and putting my script onto both of them would fix the problem.

The script works, but the effect in game is like the player is touching and grabbing things with 2 invisible boxes around him.

Is there any way to let the invisible boxes pass through my game objects to grab them while still causing the OnCollisionStay function to be executed?

Here's my script:

```
#pragma strict
var agarrado: boolean;
var cosa : Collision;
function OnCollisionStay(other : Collision) {
    if (other.transform.position.y < transform.position.y-1.5) 
        return;
    if(Input.GetKeyUp("e")){
        cosa = other;
        agarrado= true;
    }
}

function Update()
{
    if(agarrado)
    {
        cosa.transform.position.x = transform.position.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! As a heads up: Unity actually refers to a Microsoft Inversion of Control framework. When tagging, be sure to use Unity3D.

Comment: @NickUdell thanks for the corrections and the advise! Is there any way to give you a like for your job?

Comment: As your reputation increases you can vote up comments, but I wouldn't worry about it. Just glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your two box colliders triggers for your objects to pass through them by ticking the "isTrigger" checkbox on the box collider components in the inspector.

Then simply replace OnCollisionStay with [OnTriggerStay](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay.html)

```
OnCollisionStay(other: Collision)
```

becomes

```
OnTriggerStay(other: Collider)
```